# Sprites distorted or not present after multiple game reload in andengine

Tags: andengine

In AndEngine If I reload for many times (more the 2 or 3) the game some of the sprites appears distorted or doesn't appear. At first I encountered the problem more frequently and it seems that reloadTextures() and reloadFonts() reduces the frequency of the error, but still the problem not solved. What can be the problem ?

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of the problem?